# Layout not aligning

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I have two containers, one on top of the other. The bottom one is wider than the top and both have auto margins to the left and right. I figure the top one should sit even on top of the other.

I have no idea what's causing this imbalance. The only solution that remotely works is manually setting the left margins but it doesn't scale properly when resizing the screen.

It's designed to work in modern browsers. IE9, Chrome, FF. IE8 support hasn't been done yet but it will eventually need to work in IE8.

Live Demo:

http://julianjosephs.com/seniorloans/

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Your link is not working.. Could not locate remote server error.

Comment: @Julian As an aside, make sure you try viewing the site in a 4:3 monitor (or just re-size your browser to be a little smaller). Everything flips out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I see, you have set, in the `container.columns` style, the property `margin-left: 10px`.
This property is not set for the lower blue section. You can try applying an aditional left for
the footer, i.e:

`.container.footer.column.extend-width
{
    left: 10px;
}`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The `divs` with classes `.body-boder-right` and `.body-boder-right` have different widths.

```
.body-boder-left {
  ...
  width: 90px;
}

.body-boder-right {
  ...
  width: 70px;
}
```

Try setting them the same:

```
.body-boder-left {
  ...
  width: 70px;
}

.body-boder-right {
  ...
  width: 70px;
}
```

Comment: you also have different sizes of your shadows; 1 is 83 × 1 and the other is 90 x 1. If you cut the image 20 px short the shadow could come to an abrupt stop and not gradient into the background. An example of that is your left shadow on the page.